# Display a image sequence in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have 5 images that are 1.png to 5.png and stored in res/drawable folder. Now, I want to make a application to play randomly these images. First, I will make a random number from 1 to 5 such as

```
Random r = new Random();
int ii = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;//min=1 and max=5
```

After that, I will check the number, if number is 1, I will display 1.png. And so on...
I would like to ask you something about how to implement it in android.

```
//XML file
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/seq_image"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/1" >
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use a handler which checks the random Number variable after a specified time interval and changes the picture accordingly. But this would be very very inefficient, as the thread will continue till the app is not destroyed. I would suggest you go through the [Docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. set all images visibility invisible
2. use thread to dealy like:

   ```
         Thread.sleep(1000);
   ```

3.use switch or if condition to chose which image to display according to your generated random number and make that image visible while make all others invisible

```
I am suggesting something like this take it as algorithm:

    ImageView img1........img5;

    img1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    img2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
    ....
    img5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    Random r = new Random();
    int ii = r.nextInt(5 - 1 + 1) + 1;

    switch(ii){

    case 1:
        // display first image and hide others
    case 2:
        // display second image and hide others

    }

   Thread.sleep(1000);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After you generate your random number, your will combine the int and the file name then you can get the Bitmap to attach to your ImageView.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromAssets(int yourRandomNumber, String fileName) throws IOException {

        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

        InputStream istr = assetManager.open(yourRandomNumber + fileName);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);

        return bitmap;
    }
```